# How to add user into COM permission list in windows server 2012 using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, server

[image]

How can i add user into permission list using Windows PowerShell command

Comment: Use the DCOMPerm utility available from the Windows SDK is one possible track (and the simplest, IMHO). Link for download here: http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2012/11.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about dcom permission could be accessed via winregistry, HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Ole, DefaultAccessPermission / DefaultLaunchPermission, or via wmi.

Either way you need to get sid of your user, create object in SDDL format, and put it to registry. There is already few examples of powershell implementation on internet, for example [this one](https://unlockpowershell.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/script-remote-dcom-wmi-access-for-a-domain-user/).

But for real life I can suggest to do it not from powershell, but from GPO (Computer configuration - windows settings - security settings - local policies - security options - DCOM: Machine Launch/Access Restrictions in Security Descriptor Definition Language (SDDL) syntax ). Its easy, GUI-provided, could be used in SCCM compliance checks, etc etc.